# Set variable to replace parentheses and spaces

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to write a batch that could essentially replace a string like `1 (1) --> x01y01` or `20 (20) --> x20y20`. So I was working with a batch I already had that another user helped me with. I was trying to do something like

```
SET OriginalName=!OriginalName:)=!
SET OriginalName=!OriginalName: (=y!
```

This would at least remove that parentheses and space and leave me with 1y1 and 20y20 and I would try and add the rest but I don't know how to deal with the parentheses and spaces. i couldn't find an answer in [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).

Comment: You should take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Your code sample does not qualify as an MCVE.  Also, pretty sure this questions been answered here at SO more than once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have this at the beginning of your script (or at least at the beginning of the script below):

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
```

---

If the first and second number are always the same use this:

```
SET "num=!OriginalName:~,2!"
IF !num! LEQ 9 (
    SET "OriginalName=x0!OriginalName:)=!"
    SET "OriginalName=!OriginalName: (=y0!"
) ELSE (
    SET "OriginalName=x!OriginalName:)=!"
    SET "OriginalName=!OriginalName: (=y!"
)
```

Input: `1 (1)` and `20 (20)`

Output: `x01y01` and `x20y20`

---

If the first and second number are not always the same use this:

```
SET "num_1=!OriginalName:~,2!"
IF !num_1! LEQ 9 (
    SET "OriginalName=x0!OriginalName:)=!"
) ELSE (
    SET "OriginalName=x!OriginalName:)=!"
)

SET "num_2=!OriginalName:~-2!"
IF !num_2! LEQ 9 (
    SET "OriginalName=!OriginalName: (=y0!"
) ELSE (
    SET "OriginalName=!OriginalName: (=y!"
)
```

Input: `1 (20)` and `20 (1)`

Output: `x01y20` and `x20y01`

Comment: If you must use the bang delimiters, then at least enable delayed expansion in your script.  MCVE remember?

Comment: I decided to go with this one because my batch already had delayed expansion enabled like @jwdonahue had mentioned. I only had to change the `SET "num_2=!OriginalName:~-3!"` to `SET "num_2=!OriginalName:~-2!` because I was getting a conflict between `1 (1)` and `1 (10), 1 (11), etc`. Now it seems to run perfectly. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I do like the way it yields the consistent two digit output.

Comment: @FatalBulletHit, you should update your answer with Daniel's fix and add the delayed expansion.  It would then be a worthy answer.

Comment: @jwdonahue Funny enough, if I'm not mistaken, he already works with a batch I helped him out and said batch includes `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`, but I'll add it for later use... ;)

Comment: @DanielSachs It was late, must have thought the closing bracket was still there... thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: @FatalBulletHit, yeah. after I chose to use this answer, I noticed it was you and thought, "oh dang, he is the guy that helped me with the last question." My batch can go through and fix both naming conventions now.

Comment: @DanielSachs Nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

This method works in all cases, even if the numbers are of 1 or 2 digits:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "OriginalName=1 (1)"

SET "aux=%OriginalName:)=%"
SET "aux=%aux:(=% "
SET "l=xy"
set "r=" & set /A "n=%aux: =+100" & set "r=!r!!l:~0,1!!n:~-2!" & set "l=!l:~1!" & set /A "n=%0"

echo %OriginalName% --^> %r%
```

Output examples:

```
1 (1) --> x01y01
20 (20) --> x20y20
```

The method is also easily extensible to work with more values. For example, to get the result below, just modify the value of `l` variable this way: `SET "l=xyzt"`:

```
1 (20) 3 (40) --> x01y20z03t40
```

If you want to know how the method works, just remove the `@echo off` line and review it! **`;)`**